# Test self signed client side public certificate to use in 2 way SSL

Tags: ssl, testing, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I have generated 2 pairs of public certificate and keys - one for client side and other for server side, for testing if my client side public certificate is working fine.

To check  client certificate, I ran  the following command:

```
openssl s_server -cert server_cert.pem -key server_key.pem -WWW -port 12345 -CAfile client_cert.pem -verify_return_error -Verify 1
```

But I am getting the following error on running it:

```
verify depth is 1, must return a certificate
unable to load certificate
34359836736:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It appears you generated the cert file wrong. Look at it: is it in PEM format (as specified in wikipedia, or rfc7468)? What type is it? Is it CERTIFCATE or X.509 CERTIFICATE (or TRUSTED CERTIFICATE as mentioned in the error message, although in fact that is very rarely used), and not anything else?

Comment: I had generated the cert file using Java keytool. Things seem fine after generating certificates with openssl.

Comment: But I ran the same command (given in question) after using openssl, and I am getting the output:

verify depth is 1, must return a certificate
Enter pass phrase for server_private_key.pem:
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT

,    The cmd is stuck at this point. Does this mean my client certificate is successfully verified?

Comment: 'generated with keytool' leaves dozens of possibilities, many of them wrong, but you apparently don't want any help with that. When you run `openssl s_server` with a valid cert and key, it _waits for connections from (a) client(s)_. You need to make a connection from a client that uses the client key and cert, and _then_ the server validates the client cert and displays any error -- although using `-CAfile clientcert` is only correct if the client cert is selfsigned, and for a selfsigned cert validation is trivial -- it is valid if it is in the truststore and not if it isn't.

Comment: ... I.e. all the validation decisions have been made in advance manually, and the program has no options or interesting possibilities. `openssl s_client` is one such client if you don't have another you want/prefer to use.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 can you please inform about how to make connection from client to server in my local machine?

Comment: Depends on which client and which server. If you mean the `s_server` as in your Q, and `s_client` as in my comment, specify either (preferred) `-connect [hostname]:[portnum]` or `-host [hostname]` and `-port [portnum]` where hostname either is or resolves to a loopback address or an address of the (desired) machine; by convention the name `localhost` always resolves to loopback. For `s_client` to _successfully_ connect to a server that requires client auth give it a key and valid cert. Most of this is explained in the man page.